# Compile error using beta6

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

using rxjs beta2 my project works great, but updating to beta6 I get a long list of compile error:

```
component.ts(34,18): error TS2339: Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Observable<T[]>'.
....
....
.component.ts(51,10): error TS2339: Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Company>'.
....
....
service.ts(24,18): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'
....
....
node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/range.d.ts(2,16): error TS2435: Ambient modules cannot be nested in other modules.
node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/range.d.ts(2,16): error TS2436: Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name.
node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/catch.d.ts(2,16): error TS2435: Ambient modules cannot be nested in other modules.
node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/catch.d.ts(2,16): error TS2436: Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative m
..
```

I'm importing Observables like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
using rc1 rxjs beta6 works.
But I had to cast the result on all my observables.
Before I could use:

```
this._couseSourcesSvc.readAll ()
    .finally (() => sourcesSpinner.hide ())
    .subscribe (
        res => {
            this.sources = res;
        }
```

But now I have to use:

```
this._couseSourcesSvc.readAll ()
    .finally (() => sourcesSpinner.hide ())
    .subscribe (
        (res:Sources[]) => {
            this.sources = res;
        }
```

As you can see I have to cast the result or I get a compile error
*(res:Sources[])*

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'DocumentSource[]'.
```

Is this normal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `Rx.Observable`. You should be importing `import {Rx} from 'rx'`

Answer (score 2):

Only Angular2 `rc.0` (which came out just last night) supports rx beta 6.

Upgrade your angular to release candidate 1 to be able to update RxJs.

> Note you'll have to update your imports to `@angular/core` | `@angular/http` etc. The name has changed from `angular2/*`

Comment: I'm importing the following: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
` and getting the following error when using the switchMap method: `property 'switchmap' does not exist on type observable<{ [] }>`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have operators, you need to import them:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Or per operator:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

Comment: I tryed to change all my *import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';* into *import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';* but the problem remains the same